# Realizar esta petición en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, express, curl

Necesito realizar la siguiente petición desde un servidor de node.js con express:

```
curl -X POST \
     -H 'accept: application/json' \
     -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
     'https://api.mercadopago.com/oauth/token' \
     -d 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
     -d 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
     -d 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
     -d 'code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE' \
     -d 'redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI'
```

Answer (score 0):

si haces esto con frecuencia herramientas como Postman te pueden ayudar a probar las peticiones y convertirlas en código en diferentes lenguajes.

```
var qs = require("querystring");
var http = require("https");

var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "hostname": "api.mercadopago.com",
  "path": "oauth/token",
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    // body es tu respuesta, recuerda que debes hacer JSON.parse() en un try-catch antes de usarla
  });
});

// Pones el valor o la variable de cada uno de los parametros
req.write(qs.stringify({ client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
  client_secret: 'CLIENT_SECRET', 
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  code: 'AUTHORIZATION_CODE',
  redirect_uri: 'REDIRECT_URI' }));
req.end();
```

Me avisas que tal!